# Wordpress loop through posts in custom post type and group by category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

Apologies in advance if this is a question which has already been answered, I have searched extensively and can't find the exact answer to my question.

I've got a custom post type in wordpress called 'staff' and inside that post type I have a number of categories for the different groups of staff, e.g. managers, shop assistants etc... I would like to produce a page listing out all of the staff members but grouping them by their job role. So essentially looping through each category for the post type and pulling out various fields from the posts tagged with each category.

I'm really struggling to get my head around it, I can list out all of the categories from the custom post type by using wp_list_categories and defining the post type to run through but can't do the above.

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks
Thom

Comment: Query your custom post type + the desired category. Documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to dynamically go through each category, without knowing the number of them or ID's, so loop through each category in the post type and pull out all posts associated with that category. I just can't seem to get my head around how to do that.

Comment: If you don't know the category ID but the category slug/name you could use `category_name` in your loop.